# Barycenters and the axiomatic of affine geometry

Tags: reference-request, affine-geometry

There are several ways to define an affine space,
either by starting from a transitive action of a vector
space on a set of points, or listing sets of axioms
related to parallelism in the spirit of Euclid.

On the other hand, it is often said that affine geometry
is the geometry of the barycenter. It should be
possible to define an affine space by postulating
the existence of an operation called the barycenter,
$$
({\bf R} \times {\cal E}) \times ({\bf R} \times {\cal E}) \mapsto {\cal E}
$$
that is homogeneous , associative, etc, without talking
about vector spaces or parallelism at first,
and then recover the basic geometric notions from here:
an affine subspace is the set of all barycenters obtained 
from a finite set of points and so on.

I have never seen such an axiomatic, yet it seems quite natural.
Are there any references that take that path to affine geometry?

Comment: How about https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/affine+space#one_ternary_operation ?

Comment: Yes. I am seeking a reference that starts from such axiomatic
and build the theory from there.